# chef, wordpress, apache, php

Tags: wordpress, chef

I saw a project this past thursday online that does the following:

installs wordpress, apache, php, mysql all via chef and it does this on 2 servers for replication.
I can't for the life of my remember the name of the project.  Anybody seen this before?  I think it might have been on github but I really don't remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NM I figured out the link was
https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/pressupbox

Comment: Keeping your browser history clear is not always a good thing. :)